Proving this recursive merging routine from merge sort works
I was wondering if anyone could provide a proof that the following algorithm to merge $2$ sorted arrays into a combined sorted array works:
\begin{array}{l}
\texttt{function merge($x[1 \ldots k], y[1 \ldots l]$):} \\
\texttt{if $k=0$: return $y[1 \ldots l]$} \\
\texttt{if $l=0$: return $x[1 \ldots k]$} \\
\texttt{if $x[1]\le y[1]$: return $x[1] \circ  $merge$(x[2 . . . k], y[1 . . . l])$} \\
\texttt{else: return $y[1] \circ $merge$(x[1 . . . k], y[2 . . . l])$}
\end{array}
where $\circ$ denotes concatenation. I thought of trying to induct on both $k$ and $l$ to show that any sorted lists $x$ and $y$ of length $k$ and $l$ will be merged correctly by the above procedure; however, I was running into a problem because if I am to show merge$(x,y)$ working implies that merge$(x’,y)$ works where $x’$ and $y$ are any sorted lists of size $k+1$ and $l$, then if $y[1]>x[1]$ I can't use the fact that we recurse on a smaller list for $x$ and use the inductive hypothesis to guarantee that the recursive case works.
So  does anyone have a proof of the correctness of the above algorithm? For context, this is a subroutine in the famous sorting algorithm merge sort, and I am induced to prove that it works solely by my own curiosity.

Use induction on the total length $k + l$.
Suppose the statement is true for $k + l = q$, we prove it for $k + l = q + 1$.
If $k = 0$, then the first statement returns and correctness of the merge is guaranteed by the precondition that $y$ is a sorted array. Same for $l = 0$.
If $k \neq 0$ and $l \neq 0$, then there are two cases: $x[1] \leq y[1]$ and $x[1] > y[1]$. In both cases the first element of the returned array is the minimum of $x[1]$ and $y[1]$, and because $x$ and $y$ are sorted, it is the smallest one in both arrays. The correctness of the tail now follows from the induction hypothesis, because the recursive call of merge has arguments of length either $k - 1$ and $l$, or $k$ and $l - 1$, and in both cases the total length is $q$.
